# Matriz con filas y columnas muy grandes en C

Tags: c

Buenas, tengo un problema con un programa donde tengo una matriz[N][N] donde N es 9000 pero al ejecutar el programa me peta.

La cuestión es esta:
Los valores de M (matriz cuadrada de tamaño NxN, siendo N=9000) no nulos se generarán pseudoaleatoriamente y estarán comprendidos entre 0

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 9000

int main()
{
    int **matriz;
    int i,j;
    // Reserva de Memoria
    matriz = (int **)malloc(N*sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0;i<=N;i++)
        matriz[i] = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));

    rellenarMatriz(matriz);
    //imprimir(matriz);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void rellenarMatriz(int **matriz[][N])
{
    int i,j;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            if(i==j)
            {
                matriz[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else{
                matriz[i][j] = rand()%10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El error es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La declaracion de los parametros de la funcion rrellenarMatriz esta mal. Seria:
(int *matriz[],int filas , int columnas ) o (int **matriz, int filas, int columnas) o ( int matriz[][], int filas, int columnas)

Comment: ¿ Seguro que el codigo que muestras es **exactamente** el que te causa problemas ? ¿ No habrás puesto un código distinto por error ?

Answer (score 0):

No se porqué dices que *peta*; una vez corregidos los errores que **impiden que compile**, funciona:

Te falta esto:

```
#include<time.h>
```

Cambiar los tipos en tu función `rellenarMatriz( )`

```
void rellenarMatriz( int ** );
```

Añadir, antes del `main`, el prototipo de la función anterior.

Con eso, compila; aunque sigue dando un *aviso*:

> warning: unused variable 'j'

Ahora, si lo ejecutamos ... pues funciona. Y, a simple vista, parece que hace lo que se supone que deberia hacer.

Comment: ya está, con eso funciona. Gracias!!